# How link LLVM libraries

Tags: llvm, codeblocks, static-linking

I have small Code::Blocks project using LLVM. Code is already compiled but are problems with link: in /usr/localc/lib are 134 libraries with size all = 5 GB.

If I try add to CodeBlocks library by library, are errors: not found symbols. If I try add all libraries to CodeBlocks , is too much and CodeBlocks doesn't start.

LLVM has llvm-config, but how use it with CodeBlocks?

Answer (score 0):

In CodeBlocks in "Other compiler options:"
`llvm-config --cxxflags`

In CodeBlocks in "Other linker options:"
`llvm-config --ldflags --system-libs --libs core orcjit native`
or maybe other components than "core,orcjit,native"

(this is invisible in comments, but llvm-config flags should be between apostrophes)